# Lightweight fopen technique in PHP

Tags: php, fopen

I'm trying to write data to a simple txt file in PHP and open it so the user can download it. I'd like to keep it very lightweight, when I run this I get:

```
Warning: fopen(testFile.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: File exists in /home/user/script.php on line 9
```

Here is my sample code:

```
<?php

$File = "sample.txt";
$write = fopen($File, 'w') or die();
$stringData = "asdfjkl;";
fwrite($write, $stringData);
fclose($write);

$open = fopen($File, 'x') or die();
fclose($open);

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: On the docs for [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).  **Mode x**: `If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING.`.

Comment: I can't seem to locate the file though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write to the file:

```
$filename = "sample.txt";
$stringData = "asdfjkl;";
file_put_contents($filename, $stringData);
```

Then when you want to output the contents of the file use:

```
$filename = "sample.txt";
readfile($filename);
```

If you want the file contents to be returned as a string instead of output immediately use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with your example it shows the contents in the browser. Do I use fopen do prompt for a download of that instead of using readfile?

Comment: @user1062058: To open a download prompt, you need to send certain header flags.  Check the example on the [`readfile` docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: Thanks user1 and Rocket, wasn't too sure of what functions were out there. Thanks!